# Not able to access $scope property outside AngularJS controller in animation function

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

[image]

```js
angular.module("modalApp", ['ngAnimate', "ngMaterial", "ngMessages"])
    .controller('modalCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.direction = 'left';
        $scope.currentIndex = 0;
  $scope.init = true;
  $scope.initWizard = function() {
   if($scope.init) { 
    $scope.setCurrentIndex(0); 
   } 
   $scope.init = false;  
  }

        $scope.setCurrentIndex = function (index) {
            $scope.currentIndex = index;
        }
  
        $scope.isCurrentIndex = function (index) {
            return $scope.currentIndex === index;
        }

        $scope.nextModalStep = function () {
            $scope.direction = 'left';
            if($scope.currentIndex < $scope.modalSteps.length - 1) {
    ++$scope.currentIndex;
   } 
        }

        $scope.prevModalStep = function () {
            $scope.direction = 'right';
            if($scope.currentIndex > 0) {
    --$scope.currentIndex;
   } 
        }
    })
    .animation('.modalViewAnimation', function () {
        return {
   beforeAddClass: function(element, className, done) {
    var scope = element.scope();
    if (className == 'ng-hide') {
     var elementWidth = element.parent().width();
     startPoint = 0;
     if(scope.direction !== "right") {
      finishPoint = elementWidth;
     } else {
      finishPoint = -elementWidth;
     }
     TweenMax.fromTo(element, 0.5, { left: startPoint}, {x: finishPoint, onComplete: done });
    } else {
     done();
    }
   },
   removeClass: function(element, className, done) {
    var scope = element.scope();
    if (className == 'ng-hide') {
     var elementWidth = element.parent().width();
     finishPoint = 0;
     if(scope.direction !== "right") {
      startPoint = elementWidth;
     } else {
      startPoint = -elementWidth;
     }
     TweenMax.to("section", 0.5, { height: element.outerHeight()});
     TweenMax.fromTo(element, 0.5, { x: startPoint}, {x: finishPoint, onComplete: done, delay:0.25});
    } else {
     done();
    }
   }
        }
 });
```

> I have a wizard slider that is almost working. My problem is accessing the direction property in my animation function after it has been set in the controller. The scope object has value inside the animation but the dot notation of retrieving the direction property with "scope.direction" returns undefined. Why? Any help greatly appreciated. Worth mentioning, I modified the animation function ever so slightly from this https://github.com/simpulton/angular-photo-slider to achieve what I want. I can't see why my scope.direction returns undefined?

Comment: I added "var" in front of finishPoint  and startPoint variables thinking this might be affecting things , but still undefined.

Comment: interesting finding just now. the "direction" property is on the scope variable in my animation function (please see screenshot of my chrome debugger at the line of "if(scope.direction !== "right") { "       How do I access this?

Comment: the red arrow and box in the screenshot above isn't the line that is providing the debug information you see (my bad). It is from the line , if(scope.direction !== "right") {       in the animation function . The direction property is definitely in the scope variable in the childhead. I just don't know how to access it.

Comment: alright. found it. scope.$$childHead.direction accesses the variable, but why do I have to access it from the $$childHead and not root scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure the reason, but I had to get it from childHead.
The key for me was injecting rootScope.
Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ljbrown238/o0eauxq5)
(edited to 'tidy' my code ;-) )

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.onOff = false;
});

myApp.animation('.fold-animation-expand', ['$animateCss', '$rootScope',
  function($animateCss, $rootScope) {
    return {
      enter: function(element, doneFn) {
        console.log("onOff:" + $rootScope.$$childHead.onOff);
        return $animateCss(element, {
          from: {
            "font-size": '0px'
          },
          to: {
            "font-size": '20px'
          },
          duration: 2
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}
.box.ng-enter {
  transition: 2s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}
.box.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    onOff state:{{onOff}}
    <br>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="onOff?onOff=false:onOff=true">Run animation</button>
    <hr>

    <div ng-if="onOff == true" class="fold-animation-expand" style="font-size:0px">
      Expanding element
    </div>

    <hr>Example of CSS-based transition
    <br>
    <div ng-if="onOff" class="box">Animated Box</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Loren. I appreciate it. First time for me digging around in the debugger with scope.